# CSS Problema com bordas e posicionamento de elementos de lista

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estou a fazer uma componente TAB em HTML + CSS, e tenho uma dúvidas relativamente ao css, o o código que tenho é o seguinte:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700");
.tabs {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 222px;
  border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 3px; }
  .tabs__tab-list {
    list-style: none;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-right: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-left: 1px solid #E6E6E6; }
  .tabs__tab {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0; }
    .tabs__tab:first-child {
      float: left;
      width: 46%;
      height: 40px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      display: table;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-right: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
      background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    .tabs__tab:last-child {
      float: right;
      width: 54%;
      height: 40px;
      text-align: right;
      display: table;
      padding-right: 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; }
    .tabs__tab--selected {
      color: pink; }
    .tabs__tab__text {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle; }
  .tabs__content {
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs__tab-list">
    <li class="tabs__tab">
      <span class="tabs__tab__text">Tab1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__tab">
      <span class="tabs__tab__text">
        Tab2
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs__content">
    <h1>Tab2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como posso preparar este componente para levar n separadores, e sejam mostradas as bordas de forma correta? Algum exemplo/dica que me aconselham? Obrigado

Comment: Tu que remover as bordas ?

Comment: Não, eu quero o efeito das bordas, da area cinzenta.

Comment: Bom dia, tudo bem ?
Eu te acho muito melhor vc colocar 3 divs e setar os tamanhos que vc quer, e ir mexendo no display das divs, para ir deixando uma ao lado da outra ou uma em baixo outra em cima, ai vc da a borda para a div vc usa bem menos codigo.

Answer (score 3):

Cara não sei se te entendi bem, mas usando `flex` vc consegue fazer um "componente" bem responsivo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre o código as dicas que vou te dar é usar o `border-radius` no contorno do *container* e na `nav` das `tabs` vc colocar o `border-bottom`, e no `tab` item que estiver ativo vc coloca um `box-shadow` de `1px` para baixo, assim tampando a linha da `nav` e fazendo ele "se juntar" com o conteúdo abaixo. No `tab-item` vc tb coloca um `border-left` para fazer os divisores entre uma `tab` e outra, menos pro `last-child` que vc não precisa de borda a direita.

Veja o código referente a imagem acima:

```css
.tab-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.tab-container .tab-nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
.tab-container .tab-nav .tab-item:not(:last-child){
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
.tab-container .tab-nav .tab-item.ativo {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff;
}
.tab-container .tab-nav .tab-item {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab-nav">
        <div class="tab-item ativo">
            item 1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-item">
            item 2
        </div>
        <div class="tab-item">
            item 3
        </div>
        <div class="tab-item">
            item 4
        </div>
        <div class="tab-item">
            item 5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-box">
        <div class="tab-content">
            content item 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Penso que resolveu parte do problema, como posso remover a border lateral dos outros elementos e aplicar um border-radius co canto superior do lado direito e do canto inferior do lado esquerdo do elemento selecionado?

Comment: @CláudioHilário Cara isso vc tem que fazer em parte com CSS e parte com JavaScript. Tipo assim, quando vc clicar no tab-item vc mostra o conteúdo dele e esconde o conteúdo dos outros, ao mesmo tempo que vc remove a classe ativo do outro item e coloca apenas no item que vc clicou... Eu não entendi direto essa parte de como vc quer os border redius do item ativo mas basta vc colocar as estilos na classe .ativo e como falei usar JS para colocar essa classe só no item clicado. Eu não entendo de JS ou jQuery então no consigo te ajudar muito nessa.

Comment: @CláudioHilário Mas agora que vc já tem o layout vc pode abrir um "Pergunta Nova" e ver se alguém te ajuda com o Script. Ou se vc preferir pode procurar por algum componente pronte de "Responsive Tabs" vc deve encontrar várias opções pela net

Comment: Quanto ao script, já tenho a funcionalidade implementada em reactjs, o problema é na classe ativo, quando tenho um “separador” ativo queria que esse tivesse as bordas top com uma curvatura de 3 px e o “separador” a direita/esquerda caso existem tenham uma border bottom de 3px junto ao separador ativo, alguém pode dar uma ajudinha?

Comment: @CláudioHilário acho que te entendi, assim que der eu vou dar uma editada nesse código e fazer os estilos que faltam só não te garanto que vou conseguir ver isso hj... Já comecei a beber... :D

Comment: Hahaha muito obrigado pela ajuda :D

Comment: @CláudioHilário cara eu comecei a mexer aqui, mas o resultado não ta ficando legal não... o btn ativo fica com o canto redondo e o canto do lato fica reto. Está bem estranho e feio na verdade... Vc tem alguma imagem com o modelo que pretende? Um exemplo de como quer que fique?

Comment: como exemplo, do google chrome, eu fiz um print, está neste link: https://imgur.com/l2ej4Z6 Obrigado

Comment: @CláudioHilário Esse tipo de curvatura na base da Tab tipo um "border-radius pra fora" não é tão simples de fazer quanto parece. Além disso como ficaram quando tivessem mais de 2 Abas? E como deve ficar o estilo da Aba ativa no meio das outras abas?

Comment: Quando está ativa, ficaria como na imagem (branca com a "border-radius" para fora), as que não estão ativas sem borda, ou melhor com borda no fundo :D

Comment: Conseguiu ver alguma coisa?

Comment: @CláudioHilário não. Como te falei só esse border-radius invertido já daria uma pergunta a parte, pois é complicado de fazer, ainda mais associado a um componente dinâmico como esse. Te sugiro que contrate um web-designer ou um dev. front-end para fazer um exatamente do jeito que vc quer. Ou então tente achar um componente de Abas pronto.